# Securing data locally until next online access

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I am not a crypto expert, so I would like to know what is the best way to achieve the following.

I am building some software that requires to:

1. Access a cloud service.
2. Keep some data locally, with sensitive data that the our client app *must write* but the user should never be able to write herself.
3. All things are done offline and locally until the user accesses the cloud again. We have tokens with expiration dates.

So we need to secure:

- Balance: our client app must be able to read it and write it locally. But the user should not be able to overwrite it.
- Token expiry date: our client must read it, but nothing else.

The token is returned by the cloud service.

- Q1: What is a secure scheme for writing the balance locally without the user being able to find/break the key?
- Q1b: Is it even possible to achieve security and offline mode at the same time?

I find the problem in the fact that if we want to write the balance, the user will have a key in her computer already, wether embedded in the software or in disk. So if the user has a key, she could maliciously use the key (if she finds it) to overwrite the balance...?

- Q2: Is it possible to have a totally (as unfeasible to break) secure setup only locally?

If this is not possible:

- Q3: I want at least to be able to make sure that the access token expiry date is properly protected as much as possible.
- Q4: In case that something gets broken, what is the best scheme to just compromise the instance of our client that is hacked, in case some key is broken?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Consider that it is virtually impossible to achieve 100% security and protecting against a user on their device is even more difficult. Define the threat model, that is the attacker and skill level you must defend against (curious teen to well funded nation state). Define the value to the attacker, the user and your service in monetary units ($, €, £, etc). Then you can defie your needs and come up with a method that satisfies the threat.

Comment: Essentially the only way tp protect against a user is to use some form of off-device (server), what you are looking for is closer to DRM than just encryption.